# Flutter : The argument type 'void Function(Country)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Country?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I faced with an error using country_currency_pickers, i suppose it's because the function should turns into null safety, but i don't know how to do this. Thanks for help in advance!

```
Widget _buildDropdownItem(Country country) => Container(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        CountryPickerUtils.getDefaultFlagImage(country),
        SizedBox(
          width: 8.0,
        ),
        Text("+${country.phoneCode}(${country.isoCode})"),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

```
                            CurrencyPickerDropdown(
                            itemBuilder: _buildCurrencyDropdownItem,
                            initialValue: 'INR',
                            onValuePicked: (Country countryvalue) {
                              print("${country.name}");
                            },
                          )
```

Comment: where is function _buildCurrencyDropdownItem ?

Answer (score 1):

just replace this

```
onValuePicked: (Country countryvalue) {
    print("${country.name}");
},
```

with

```
onValuePicked: (Country? countryvalue) {
    print("${country.name}");
},
```

Comment: I have tried it already, but its anyway underline red _buildDropdownItem and function onValuePicked with this error